# Enquiry about the proof of covariance and variance

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, conditional-probability, mathematical-physics

Suppose that I set X ∈ {0,1},

How can I prove that COV(X,Y)/VAR(X) =E(Y|X=1)−E(Y|X=0)?

I try thinking of COV(X,Y)=COV(X,E(Y|X)) and divide the term with the conditional variance.Thus, the unknown in the equation is Y.

What I have tried is as follows.

COV(X,E(Y|X))=E(X E(Y|X))-E(X)E(E(Y|X))

For the variance,

VAR(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2

However, when I divided COV with VAR. it seems that I cannot arrange the term to the answer.

Please, Any hints and guidances are very much appreciated.

Comment: I would write $p=P(X=1)=E[X]$ and then find $\text{Var}(X)$ in terms of $p$ and $\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ in terms of $p$ and $E[Y\mid X=1]$ and $E[Y\mid X=0]$

Comment: Is it like solving the E(X) and VAR(X) for the Bernoulli?    Thank you Henry.

Comment: $X$ is Bernoulli  but $Y$ need not be

Comment: Thank you Henry. At the first place, I was confused because the problem does not state anything related to the distribution of X. It seems to me that it works now.

Comment: The problem did state that $X$ was supported over a two member set, $\{0,1\}$, so ...  That's a Bernoulli.

Comment: Thanks you Graham.